# Convert text list into JSON object (javascript or jquery)

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to convert this list into JSON (see below) using Javascript or jQuery?

```
<div class="w-dyn-items">
<div class="w-dyn-item">
    <div class="select-item-country">England</div>
</div>
<div role="listitem" class="w-dyn-item">
    <div class="select-item-country">N. Ireland</div>
</div>
```

```
["England","N. Ireland"]
```

I have used various javascript methods (split, arrays etc.) to turn this text into a json array but I'm struggling to get this to work.

Some things to note:

- The HTML data above exists on the page but it's hidden. This information is pulled in via a CMS (so it's dynamic data)
- I need to convert this list into a JSON array so that I can then create cascading select/option lists (I currently use Webflow for development).

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arrayx = [];
$('.select-item-country').each(function( index ) {
$arrayx.push($(this).html());}); console.log($arrayx);
```

thats how you can do with JQ

Comment: Thanks Umut, I'll take a look at this method tomorrow. 

Comment: Worked a treat, I chose this answer as it was less code to implement with the structure that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the elements by class, and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over them returning their text content.

Note: `[...items]` converts the returned array-like static nodelist from the `querySelectorAll` results into a proper array so that `map` can work.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.select-item-country');
const values = [...items].map(item => item.textContent);
console.log(values);

// If you then need to convert it to JSON
const json = JSON.stringify(values);
console.log(json);
```

```html
<div class="w-dyn-items">
  <div class="w-dyn-item">
    <div class="select-item-country">England</div>
  </div>
  <div role="listitem" class="w-dyn-item">
    <div class="select-item-country">N. Ireland</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check this our tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you again for this answer. Both worked great and I would choose both if given the chance, however although this was definitely explained much better it was more code to implement in the project I'm working on (I used the above "Countries" as example code but actually implemented the solution with 10+ lists of different regions).